# Delete history from 100 to 150 entries in bash shell

Tags: bash, command-history

I want to delete history but not fully, suppose I have total 200 entries in my history and I want to delete from 101 to 150. Is this possible ?

I have seen multiple methods to delete history like `history -d entry_number`, `.bash_history` file, `history -c` command.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
for i in {1..50}
 do
   history -d 101
 done
```

This will delete history number `101` *50* times or each time it deletes history number 101 next time 102 will become 101.

Answer (score -1):

If you have vim you can do:

```
vim -c "101,150d | wq" your_file
```